# When I make the browser width smaller, text gets pushed off the page, and eventually disappears

Tags: html, css

Whenever I make the browser width smaller, text disappears. I want the text to stay visible, even when the browser is smaller. Any tips on how to accomplish this. I tried all major browsers and is the same.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/J8fjV/1/

My CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
height : 100%;
min-height : 100%;
} 
 body {
background : url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSz-vXYldxqtANJ0BbLtSBtGQfhKHBZhtJYUDvsAFl0vbKs4USP) center center no-repeat fixed #000000;
} 
   #wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:50%;
}
#footer {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     margin-left: 12.5%;
     width: 50%;
     background-color:#000000;
     height:30px;
}
body {color:white;}
body { font-family: 'Noto Sans', Verdana, sans-serif; 
       font-size: 12px; 
     }
h1 { 
  font-family: 'Share Tech', Verdana, sans-serif; 
  font-weight: 400; 
  font-size: 12px;
}
#main{
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
    background-color: transparent;

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 100;
    left: 500;
    right: 0;

    margin: auto;
}
   </style>
```

My HTML

```
<body style="overflow:hidden; margin:0"> 
    <div id="wrapper">   
    <div id="footer"><h1>Text here</h1>    </div>
</div> 


<div id="main">Text</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with _disappears_?

Comment: i've added a jsfiddle demo to your question. the text stays visible though.

Comment: kasper thanks for the link, yes it does not disappear when in jsfiddle, i cant understand.

Comment: putvande i mean i have no bar in my page when i make it smaller so i can't see the text.

Comment: making the browser window 'smaller'? can we know how much small? Is it to mobile resolution or something like 10px etc? 
bcoz, I find that the text doesn't disappear in fiddle..

Comment: skshoyeb, i don't care about mobile resolution, just when a user make smaller his browser i want the text to be visible, i think if i have the scroll bar, in the browser it will be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really understand the use of the `#wrapper` element.

Try deleting it. Then set the css of `#footer` to:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width:100%;
background-color:#000000;
height:30px;
```

You will then want to add:

```
width:100%;
white-space:nowrap;
text-align:center;
padding:0;
```

to the `#h1` css.

Tell me if it gives you what you were looking for...

Comment: Yes Max that made the trick, i have scrollbars back, so when i make browser smaller i can use the scrollbar, thank you for the corrections and the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal thing unfortunately. If you made your browser 10 px by 10 px some of the text would have to disappear.

There are ways to make it work better though.

The Twitter bootstrap library handles some of it better if you are starting early enough that you want to investigate a "framework" for your page. This will allow shrinking browsers to handle a navbar better for example.

CSS3's media is what you are interested in to set specific CSS rules for when the browser is set to a smaller size. This will allow you to control what happens when the browser shrinks.

Comment: Thanks, but i want to avoid bootstrap, i will check the css3 media stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are asking. If you add `word-wrap: break-word;` in the css, the text will go to the next line and therefore be visible.

Comment: Max thanks, but doesn't change anything when i use this line.